# How do I populate cells and handle error in data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Here is what I have set up as an example: [Simple messy data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXouq.png)

Does anyone know formula that will populate the cells with sales and marketing job ratings based on the simple data above on the left? And say if there is an error in the data on the left, I want to manage this by printing "error data".

I know I can just select the cell and then drag it down. But I want to have a single formula that can handle this. Any ideas?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your version of Excel, you can combine `IFNA`, `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions:

```
=IFNA(INDEX($B$2:$B$11,MATCH($D2 & " | " & E$1,$A$2:$A$11,0)),"Error")
```

OR

Use the `XLOOKUP` function.

```
=XLOOKUP($D2 & " | " & E$1,$A$2:$A$11,$B$2:$B$11,"Error",0)
```

[image: IFNA, INDEX, MATCH formula]

[image: XLOOKUP formula]

Comment: Reddy thanks for your lovely reponse!!! Really helps!

Comment: You can mark the question as answered if the answer has resolved your issue. Please see the [tour](https://superuser.com/tour).

Comment: Hey Reddy, I have posted another question, do you mind taking a look? Thanks :) https://superuser.com/questions/1679387/using-vlookup-in-a-simple-context-confusion

Comment: Reddy is it possible to use Vlookup  function instead?

Comment: @AliceRathbone `VLOOKUP($D$2 & " | " & E$1,$A$2:$B$3,2)`.