# Using VLOOKUP in a simple context confusion

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Here is what I have set up as a simple example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zzwgu.jpg

So I want to create an email address for interns using their initials. For example, I want to create “Alice.Peterson@outlook.com” based on his/her initials and their specific email domain, in this case APET (table on the right) . And I have a small list of names.

I have done a bit of research and think VLOOKUP might be helpful, does anyone know how to use VLOOKUP to do this? Or any other ways its fine.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the first table ranges from A1 to C7, and the second from G7 to H7, insert the following formula in C2:

```
=$A2 & "." & $B2 & "@" & VLOOKUP(LEFT($A2,1) & LEFT($B2,3),$G$2:$H$7,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

Drag the formula down to fill the cells below.

You can also use a combination of `LEFT`, `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions:

```
=$A2 & "." & $B2 & "@" & INDEX($H$2:$H$7,MATCH(LEFT($A2,1) & LEFT($B2,3),$G$2:$G$7,0))
```

Drag it down to the other cells. Note if you are using a different regional setting, you need to replace each `,` with `;` on the formula.

**Explaination:**

- `LEFT($A2,1) & LEFT($B2,3)`: finds the inter initial based on the first letter of their first name and the first 3 letters of their last name.
- `MATCH(LEFT($A2,1) & LEFT($B2,3),$G$2:$G$7,0))`: finds the row that relates to the intern's initial.
- `INDEX($H$2:$H$7,MATCH(LEFT($A2,1) & LEFT($B2,3),$G$2:$G$7,0))`: finds the email domain
- `$A2 & "." & $B2 & "@" & INDEX($H$2:$H$7,MATCH(LEFT($A2,1) & LEFT($B2,3),$G$2:$G$7,0))`: builds the email address based on the first name, last name and email domain.

[image]

Comment: Hi Reddy thanks for the response. But what if I want to use VLOOKUP?

Comment: @AliceRathbone See edit.

Comment: Thanks lovely! Super helpful!

Comment: Heyy Reddy, can you see my next post? https://superuser.com/questions/1679831/how-to-do-i-extract-multiple-characters-from-a-string-in-excel-and-use-vlookup I am kinda confused