# How to do I extract multiple characters from a string in excel and use VLOOKUP?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following simple data --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/88CSv.jpg

[image]

I want to fill up the annual salary of Amazon and facebook use VLOOKUp as according to the table on the right. To do this I need to first extract Characters from the Assistant titles.

For example, one of the assistant title is  “Personal Assistance (PeAs)”, which matches with “PA", and I want to fill the data corsspondingly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should follow @teylyn's advice and have lookup colum to make things easier. In case you can't, try the following:

Assuming the first table extends from columns A to C, and the second from columns G to I, in cell B3, enter the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT($A3,1) & MID($A3,FIND(" ",$A3,1)+1,1),$G$1:$I$4,2,0)
```

And in C3:

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT($A3,1) & MID($A3,FIND(" ",$A3,1)+1,1),$G$1:$I$4,3,0)
```

Drag the formulae down.

To have one formula instead of the two mentionned above, in C3 enter:

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT($A3,1) & MID($A3,FIND(" ",$A3,1)+1,1),$G$1:$I$4,COLUMN(I$2)-COLUMN($G$2)+1,0)
```

Drag the formula down.

Comment: @AliceRathbone To use the `CONCATENATE` function:  `VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(LEFT($A3,1), MID($A3,FIND(" ",$A3,1)+1,1)),$G$1:$I$4,2,0)`.

Comment: @AliceRathbone See edit.

Comment: @AliceRathbone "is it possible to do this with IF functions or some logical tests?" To do what? What do you want to test? What have you tried? You need to ask/create another question as we are moving away from this current question.

Comment: Reedy Sorry, I will delete them, I tried some other functions and they worked. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @AliceRathbone you don't need to delete anything. Ask another question, so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Though it may be possible to construct a complicated formula that extracts the first letters of the first two words in the Assistant Titles column, it will be way easier to add a column with the Assistant Title values to the lookup table. Then you can do a simple lookup fomula with Vlookup or Xlookup.

Any table relationship for looking up values should have a common key. That's one of the principles of table relationships.